# Failed to deploy web package to App Service

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-appservice

my azure app service zip deployments keep failing for error "Failed to deploy web package to App Service" and "Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Bad Request (CODE: 400)

I see many similar questions but I don't find any solution, I am really puzzled about what causes the issue and what is solution is possible if anyone experiences this problem.

Comment: What is the app? did you try to debug using Kudu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see many similar questions but I don't find any solution, I am
> really puzzled about what causes the issue and what is solution is
> possible if anyone experiences this problem.

Theoretically, there should be no problem, because it is just an upload operation.

Below is the CLI command I use:

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group 0730BowmanWindow --name 1009bowman --src netcoreapp3.1.zip
```

Therefore, consider the following two directions:

1, How is your app service created? Is it created using CLI and contains illegal characters? (In my case, I have no problems using English letters and numbers)

2, Whether the size of the app service is too large to be deployed.

3, It may also be an inexplicable error caused by missing some files when creating the app service, and sometimes you must choose to recreate it. Please try to recreate the app service to see if the same problem persists.